# c# executable that connects to "Visual Studio Online" (vso) fails via SQL Job Agent

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, ssis

I have created an executable using C# that connects to VSO, fetches workitems and updates them.

Here is the code used to connect to VSO and get the project:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjectCollection = null;
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
ICredentials credential = (ICredentials)networkCredential;
Uri tfsUri = new Uri(tfsUrl);

TfsConfigurationServer tfai = new TfsConfigurationServer(tfsUri, (ICredentials)credential);

try
{
    tfai.EnsureAuthenticated();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Auth fail.({0})", ex.Message));
}
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamProjectCollectionService tpcService = tfai.GetService<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamProjectCollectionService>();

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.CatalogNode configurationServerNode = tfai.CatalogNode;

System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.CatalogNode> tpcNodes = configurationServerNode.QueryChildren(new Guid[] { Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection }, false, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.CatalogQueryOptions.None);

foreach (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.CatalogNode tpcNode in tpcNodes)
{
    if (tpcNode.Resource.DisplayName.ToUpper() == "PROJECTNAME")
    {
        tfsTeamProjectCollection = tfai.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Guid(tpcNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceID"]));
        foundProject = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(foundProject)
{
    WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
}
```

The code works fine.
Even the exe of the same code works fine when run manually.

I have created an SSIS package, the execute process task runs this exe fine when run manually.

But when I deploy the package and run it via SQL Agent job, it fails with an error:

> Error: In Executing "name.exe" "" at "". The process exit code was
>   "-532462766" while the expected was "0".

I have tried running the package in 32 bit and 64 bit environment. Every time it fails with the same error.

All the users (SQLSERVERINSTANCE, SQLSERVERAGENT, SERVICEACCOUNT) have access to the executable.

Am I missing anything? Or do I have to make some changes at server side for SQL Agent to be able to connect to VSO?

P.S.: I am using SQL SERVER 2016.

Comment: You are using the SOAP client, which is being deprecated and should no longer be used. Use the REST client. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/05/21/announcing-the-deprecation-of-the-wit-and-test-client-om-at-jan-1-2020-2/

Answer (score 0):

"All the users (SQLSERVERINSTANCE, SQLSERVERAGENT, SERVICEACCOUNT) have access to the executable." doesn't mean these accounts have access to the resource, e.g. references, used in the executable.

You need to create a agent account with enough permissions and use it to run the job step.

See: [SQL Credentials and Proxy for Agent Job](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36797.sql-credentials-and-proxy-for-agent-job.aspx)

Comment: I tried it. But I get a different error now.
It says, I don't have access to VSO when I actually have it. I can explore through manually. Pasting the error in next comment.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://project-name.visualstudio.com/. at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.EnsureTokenProvider(HttpWebResponse webResponse) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest() at

Comment: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.LocationWebService.Connect(Int32 connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, Int32 features) at

Comment: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.Connect(ConnectOptions connectOptions) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureProviderConnected() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServer.get_CatalogNode() at VSO_Automation_Modified.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\v-tokudc\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VS_Automation_Modified\VS_Automation_Modified\Program.cs:line 57. Process Exit Code -532462766. The step failed.